# Mongodb fails to add all element from an $addToSet operator, omitting some elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a store and a product. I'm trying to add a product to a user's cart only if the product exists in the database. Immediately a request to add a product to a cart comes in, the product collection is queried to check the existence of the product and if the product exists, I update the cart with:

1. The id of the store the product belongs to, gotten from the initial product query.
2. The id of the product also gotten from the same initial query that checks for product existence.
3. The quantity of the product coming from the request payload.
4. The price also coming from the product query as before.

The problem now is that; only the product id and quantity of the product is saved, omitting both price and store id.

**Here is the Schema for the product**

```
var ProductModelSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    desc: {type: String, required: true},
    images: {type: Array, required:true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
    category: {type: String, required: true},
    store: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'store'},
    uploadDate: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
    uploadedby: {type: String, required: true},
});
```

**Here is the Schema for the Cart**

```
var CartModelSchema = new Schema({
    _userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required:true, ref: 'user'},
    items: [{
           _id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required:true, ref: 'product', unique: true},
            qty:{type: Number, required: true},
            store: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'store', unique: true},
            price: {type: Number, required: true}
        }],
})
```

```
   module.exports = {
         addtocart: (req, res)=>{
             let payload = req.decoded;
             User.findOne({_id: payload.user}, (error, user)=>{
                 if(error){
                     return res
                         .status(403)
                         .json(ERR("Error encountered, user unknown"));
                 }if(user){
                      //if user is signed in, query product collection for the particular product
                     Product.findOne({name: req.body.name}, (error, product)=>{
                         if(error){
                             return res
                                 .status(403)
                                 .json(ERR("Error encountered while searching for product"));
                         }if(product){
                     // if product exist in the product collection, query cart to check if it already contains product
                            Cart.findOne({'items._id': product._id, _userId: user._id}, (error, item)=>{
                                if(error){
                                    return res
                                         .status(402)
                                         .json(ERR("Error encountered when searching for item in your Cart"));
                                }
                             // Product cannot be re-added to cart, if already present
                                if(item){
                                    return res
                                     .status(403)
                                     .json(ERR("We can't re-add an already existing item to your Cart"));
                                }else{
                         //if product never existed in the cart, update cart by adding the product id, product quantity, product price,and product store to the cart items array
                                     Cart.updateOne({_userId: user._id},
                                         {$addToSet:{items: [{_id: product._id, qty: req.body.qty, store: product.store, price: product.price}]}},
                                         {upsert: true},
                                         (error, cart)=>{
                                             if(error){
                                                 return res
                                                     .status(403)
                                                     .json(ERR("Issue encountered while trying to add item to cart"));
                                             }if(cart){
                                                 return res
                                                     .status(200)
                                                     .json(SUCCESS(product.name + " added to cart"));
                                             }else{
                                                 return res
                                                     .status(403)
                                                     .json(ERR("problem"))
                                             }
                                         })
                                     }
                            })
                         }else{
                             return res
                                 .status(401)
                                 .json(ERR("The product you asked for doesn't exist"))
                         }
                     })
                 }else{
                     return res
                         .status(404)
                         .json(ERR("User does not exist."))
                 }
           })
       }}
```

This is the postman query [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeJIB.png)

This is the output I got after testing the endpoint

```
 db.carts.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f3a636f0bba3e016eb7dc14"),
        "_userId" : ObjectId("5eebaf66ee5dab56e85b9576"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5f2c0e1c832b456fe8228f54"),        
                        "qty" : 1
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Debug your code to determine if the problem is with the retrieval of data (you are not getting the price in the first place) or with persistence (price is not saved).

Comment: Yeah, I was importing a wrong (or old) model in my controller. I changed my working model but forgot to update my controller to use the new model. But I've been able to solve it now.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve the problem, I imported a wrong model, it was an old model that has only _id and qty as the item object properties.